# Handeling Dictionary of lists using Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a single dictionary that contains four keys each key representing a file name and the values is nested lists as can be seen below:

```
{'file1': [[['1', '909238', '.', 'G', 'C', '131', '.', 'DP=11;VDB=3.108943e02;RPB=3.171491e-01;AF1=0.5;AC1=1;DP4=4,1,3,3;MQ=50;FQ=104;PV4=0.55,0.29,1,0.17', 'GT:PL:GQ', '0/1:161,0,131:99'], ['1', '909309', '.', 'T', 'C', '79', '.', 'DP=9;VDB=8.191851e-02;RPB=4.748531e-01;AF1=0.5;AC1=1;DP4=5,0,1,3;MQ=50;FQ=81.7;PV4=0.048,0.12,1,1', 'GT:PL:GQ', '0/1:109,0,120:99']......,'008_NTtrfiltered': [[['1', '949608', '.', 'G', 'A',...}
```

My question is how to check only the first two elements in the list for instance "1", "909238" for each of the key if they are the same and then write them to a file. The reason I want to do this is I want to filter only common values (only the first two elements of the list) for the four files (keys).

Thanks a lot in advance
Best.

Comment: What's wrong with `my_dict["the_file_you_want"][0][0][{0 or 1}]`?

Comment: does your values has a same dimension?

Comment: @EMBLEM Hi EMBLEM, I tried it and didn't work.

Comment: @Kasra they have the same dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to the keys of the dictionary *dictio* and make your comparison using :

```
f = open('file.txt','w')
value_to_check_1 = '1'
value_to_check_2 = '909238'

for k in dictio:
   value_1 = dictio[k][0][0][0]
   value_2 = dictio[k][0][0][1]
   if (( value_1 == value_to_check_1) and (value_2 == value_to_check_2)):
          f.write('What you want to write\n')
f.close()
```

If you want to do a check that imply every values of your dictionary dictio.

Maybe you want to store couples of values from *dictio*.

```
couples = [(dictio[k][0][0][0], dictio[k][0][0][1]) for k in dictio]
```

Then, you can do a loop and iterate over the couples to do your check.

Example you can adapt according to your need :

```
for e in values_to_check:
     for c in couples:
           if (float(e[0][0][0]) >= float(c[0]) and float(e[0][0][1]) <= float(c[1])):
                     f.write(str(e[0][0][0]) + str(e[0][0][1])  + '\n')
```

Comment: thanks for your help. The values to be checked are going to be between the values wihin the dictionary and not comparison with the values you declared "value_to_check_1" and "value_to_check_1" . Also,when I tried your way it does only go over a one or single iteration of the value and then it ends the checking but my goal is to check through the entire dictionary of values between the four keys and not only on a single iteration of value.I hope my description is clear. Thanks a lot once again.